# Text format field missing for minimal installation

Tags: entities, users, 8, input-formats

I installed minimal version of latest stable Drupal 8. It does not include any HTML text formats so I had to add my own custom Full HTML text format next to default Plain Text.

It also doesn't include any content types, so I had to create my own Basic page content type with Body field.

When adding/editing content under body field it doesn't show the Text format field drop-down and I cannot select neither out of two formats, it just loads up some default CKEditor.

[image]

Also with minimal installation it doesn't include Administrator role. So I did create my own custom Administrator role and gave it all permissions, including under Filter, but still no effect, even though I'm user/1.

How do I get `Text format` working/displaying on Minimal installation?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How do I get Text format thing?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the standard profile:

```
core/profiles/standard/config/install
```

In comparision the minimal is rather empty:

```
core/profiles/minimal/config/install
```

You can take this yml-file for the text format, put it in the sync-folder and import it:

```
core/profiles/standard/config/install/filter.format.full_html.yml
```

But probably you need much more configuration, did you consider to start over with the standard profile?

Comment: You have to chose full install just for text format? Shouldn't there be a documentation stating what you lose on minimal installation then? I chose minimal because full D8 is slow as hell on windows localhost.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Drupal is an open source project. You're free to contribute any lacking documentation you see fit. The Community would thank you.

Comment: Then my question would be what's the point of text format filters feature and settings in Minimal profile if you cannot use it anywhere? I see it as a bug, if you can create filter formats, but cannot use it, because Text format field is missing.

Comment: If you create them then they should definitely show up. Might be a caching problem, try to clear all caches and if that solves it, create a bug report about that. If that doesn't ,also create one. both with detailed steps on how to reproduce.